# How detect in vanilia javascript end of video in tag <OBJECT> html?

Tags: javascript, hbbtv

I must use tag object type="video/mp4" in my project for hbbtv, and I want detect end of movie in vanilia JS. How can i do it?

Comment: I think this is covered by the CE-HTML spec, but I don't have a copy or the desire to pay for one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. This documentation ce-html is use on all smart tv with hbbtv? Some people have tv from 2012 and i have to use old old old javascrip, to launch the application.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('objectId').addEventListener('ended',endCallback,false);

function endCallback(e) {
       //Action
}
```

Comment: I think `<Object></Object>` supports `ended` event.

Comment: Probably The Object isn't supported by event media.
I tried and did nothing.

Comment: @macMod are you using .swf to play videos inside <object> or directly ?

Answer (score 0):

When using the AVControl object,  you have to register the PlayStateChange event and check playState 5 (Finished).

```
    document.getElementById('objectId').onPlayStateChange = function() {
    if (document.getElementById('objectId').playState == 5) {  // FINISHED }
    };
```

http://www.oipf.tv/docs/OIPF-T1-R2_Specification-Volume-5-Declarative-Application-Environment-v2_3-2014-01-24.pdf
7.14.1 The A/V Control object